# Why am i getting these errors from GitHub?

Tags: github, putty, tortoisegit

I followed these [instruction](http://groups.google.com/group/github/browse_thread/thread/21fd06fb8c3f43bd/f5c44b2197d1be15) and could not connect to github for the life of me.

```
>plink -ssh github.com
FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available

plink -ssh git@github.com
You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
```

with tortoisegit

```
git.exe push    "origin" master

ERROR: Permission to name/MyEmptyRepoOnGitHubHere denied to name.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Whats going on?

NOTE: I followed the instructions carefully. It was a lot worse before i followed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure if this was the solution was cloning first (the instructions say to push)and by using the url like `git@github.com:NAME/REPO.git` without skipping the `git@`

Answer (score -1):

More info here - [Problem connecting to GitHub on Windows, even via PuTTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601592/problem-connecting-to-github-on-windows-even-via-putty/5033371#5033371)